# Sum specific items from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

I have a dictionary named `dict` with 50 items but -unfortunately- names do not have a specific pattern.

I want to get the sum of specific variables and do some checks:

```
dict[random_name_sum] == dict['random_name_1'] + dict['random_name_2'] + dict['random_name_3']
```

but the following error appears:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

I searched for similar questions, but none of them can solve my problem, and the only solution I can think of is changing the data structure that may require some future manual actuons. I would like to avoid that. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us an example of your dict? Possible keys/values?

Comment: Could it be that some of the values inside the dict are list and some are int?

Comment: It cannot be that you **actually** want to do something like `[1, 2] + 3`. So, re-think what your goal is.

Comment: @TerryA yes of course.
u'array': u'[[1.0, 3.0, 2.78, 0.0]]'
u'average': 0
'std': 1.7307894041470591

Comment: @manosbar And why would you want to add the standard deviation to the average and the sample itself? What would that yield?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis the variables are random, just to show the different data that may appear in my dictionary... I am not *actually* adding these. What does it have to do with my problem though?

Comment: @manosbar As the Error says, you are adding lists to integers. You cannot do that! This: `dict['array'] + dict['average']` is not valid in your case.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis have you seen the 4th comment,

Comment: This dict has this format `'array': u'[[1.0, 3.0, 2.78, 0.0]]' u'average': 0 'std': 1.7307894041470591`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if the return type is int for the dict values because it seems like you have a list.